# Compaq Presario CQ50 Dead Motherboard

Tags: motherboard, compaq-laptop

I have acquired a 15.4 " Compaq Presario cq50 laptop with a dead motherboard. It has an AMD Sempron processer.

I wanted to replace the motherboard, however I am unsure what exactly to replace it with, what's compatible, etc.

I was looking at this one [here](http://www.komplett.ie/Komplett/product/ZKB_01COM/15_MOBO/01_AMD/productdetails/20022826/MSI_870A_G54_Motherboard_ATX/870A_G54/default.aspx) and I wondered what others thought? If anyone has any recommendations also that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a desktop motherboard.  Generally the only thing you can put in a laptop is the original board (or something from a very similar laptop) because laptop designs are so proprietary, with so many components crammed in small spaces, that nothing else fits properly (never mind the connectors).

You need to look for an original OEM motherboard for this specific laptop model.  You may have difficulty, but that's the nature of the beast.

Comment: Hmm, this may prove more difficult than I thought. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: +1  There will only be one MB for that model.  As noted, it is very spcific and could be hard to find.  Especially if MBs were an issue